# Is it possible to specify git.exe location during server-side checkout

Tags: git, teamcity

When setting up Git source control settings in TeamCity, it is possible to specify git.exe location. However, these settings are valid only for agent-side checkout.

[image: TeamCity]

Is it possible to do the same for server-side checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TeamCity uses jgit library on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

As of at least version 10 (or 2017.1) you can now specify a path to Git on the server side using the `teamcity.server.git.executable.path` internal property.

Details of the various properties relating to server side checkout can be found on the [TeamCity Git Documentation page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Git#Git-InternalProperties).